# Get avg for every ro in sql

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables:

```
pracownicy

    z a
    trybutami:
    NR_PRAC
    int NOT NULL,
    NAZWISKO char(15),
    PLEC char(1) NOT NULL,
    DATA_UR datetime ,
    NR_ZESP
    smallint NOT NULL

    zespoły
    z atrybutami:
    NR_ZESP
    smallint NOT NULL,
    NAZWA_ZESP char(30) NOT NULL,
    NR_PRAC_KZ int

    tematy
    z atrybutami:
    NR_TEM
    int NOT
    NULL,
    DATA_ROZP datetime,
    DATA_ODB datetime ,
    NR_PRAC_KT int,
    TEMAT char(30) NOT NULL,

    wypłaty
    z atrybutami
    :
    NR_PRAC int NOT NULL,
    NR_TEM int NOT NULL,
    DATA_NALICZ datetime NOT NULL,
    DATA_WYPL datetime,
    KWOTA decimal(10, 1) NOT NULL
```

Now I want to show avg Kwota for every pracownicy.Nazwisko. I write something like that:

```
Select pracownicy.nazwisko, AVG(wyplaty.kwota) from pracownicy, wyplaty group by pracownicy.nazwisko;
```

but this solution return avg all rows from wyplaty.Kwota. How can I get avg kwota for every nazwisko?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a condition for the join you have written. Also, better to use the "join" syntax; it makes it clear what the condition is for.

```
Select pracownicy.nazwisko, AVG(wyplaty.kwota) from pracownicy
inner join wyplaty on pracownicy.nr_prac = wyplaty.nr_prac
group by pracownicy.nazwisko;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly join pracownicy with wyplaty:

```
select pracownicy.nazwisko, AVG(wyplaty.kwota) from pracownicy, wyplaty
where pracownicy.NR_PRAC=wyplaty.NR_PRAC
group by pracownicy.nazwisko;
```